# How can I use reactJS within SpringBoot project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot

I am a Java developer trying to use ReactJS to present the data I am getting back from a rest API, I read different posts about the need of installing browserify to compile the jsx files, etc but ran into some issues during the installation process

> "Error: 140737135018944:error:14077410:SSL
>   routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure"

and was wondering if there is a simple way to make things running without the need of installing anything extra, The way that things are explained in different blogs is targeting someone who has a frontend experience and I don't have that knowledge to know if there is something missing, I kept trying to solve the issue but ended up in a rabbit hole, Anyway here is what I have and I hope that I can get a layman answer to make this project up and running. Fell free to ask me any questions, I would be happy to provide more details if necessary !!

I have a file called WeatherBoard.jsx which imports other react components but I am getting this error

> Uncaught SyntaxError:
>   http://localhost:8080/demo/js/WeatherManager.jsx: Unexpected token
>   (54:2)   52 |             );   53 |         }
>
> > 54 | });
> >          |   ^   55 |    56 | // Render    57 | ReactDOM.render(  ,
> >         at Parser.pp.raise (browser.min.js:41)
> >         at Parser.pp.unexpected (browser.min.js:42)
> >         at Parser.pp.expect (browser.min.js:42)

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/neo.css">

 <title>Weather </title>
</head>
 <body>
  <div id="main" class="container">
   
  </div>
  <script type="text/babel" src="js/WeatherManager.jsx"></script> 
 </body>
</html>
```

```js
var Wind=require(['Wind'],
Sys=require(['Sys'],
Main=require(['MAin'],
Coord=require(['Coord'],
WeatherManager= React.createClass({
  
 getInitialState: function() {
   
   var weather={};

   return {
    weather
   };
   
  },
  componentDidMount() {
      fetch('http://localhost:8080/demo/async/weatherInCity') 
             .then(result=>result.json())
             .then(weather=>this.setState({weather}));
  },
  render: function() {
   return(<div id="section">
    <span> City : {this.state.weather.name} </span> 
    <br/>
    <span> Date :  {this.state.weather.dt}  </span> 
    <br/>
    <span> Cod  : {this.state.weather.cod}  </span>
    <br/>
    <span> Visibility : {this.state.weather.visibility}  </span> 
    <br/>
    <span> Base : {this.state.weather.base}  </span> 
    <br/>
    <span> Id : {this.state.weather.id}   </span> 
    <br/>
    
    <span> Sys : </span> 
     <Sys sys={this.state.weather.sys}/>
    <br/>
    
    <span> Wind : </span> 
     <Wind wind={this.state.weather.wind}/>
    <br/>
  
    <span> Coord : </span> 
     <Coord coord={this.state.weather.coord}/>
    <br/>
     <span> Main : </span> 
     <Main main={this.state.weather.main}/>
    <br/>
    
   </div>);
  }
});

// Render 
ReactDOM.render( <WeatherManager /> ,
  document.getElementById('main')
);
```

Here is an example of one of the components :

```js
var WeatherManager= React.createClass({
 render: function() {
  var wind=this.props.wind;
  if(wind){
   return(<div>
    Wind Speed : {wind.speed}
    <br/>
    Wind deg   : {wind.deg}
    <br/>
    Wind gust  : {wind.gust}
    <br/>
   </div>);
  }else{
   return(<div>
   No data available 
  </div>);
  }
  
 }
});
```